# With the Skulker feat, can you hide in the cover of darkness even against creatures with darkvision?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, stealth, vision-and-light

Basically, am I able to sneak up to a target that has darkvision as if I were invisible? I believe I can for the following reasons (but would like confirmation).

The description of the [Skulker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/skulker) feat (PHB, p. 170) says:

> You are expert at slinking through shadows. You gain the following benefits:
>
> - You can try to hide when you are **lightly obscured** from the creature from which you are hiding.
> - When you are hidden from a creature and miss it with a ranged weapon attack, making the attack doesn't reveal your position.
> - Dim light doesn’t impose disadvantage on your Wisdom (Perception) checks relying on sight.

The rules on [vision and light](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/adventuring#VisionandLight) (PHB, p. 183) state:

> In a **lightly obscured** area, such as dim light, patchy fog, or moderate foliage, creatures have disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight.
>
> [...]
>
> **Dim light**, also called shadows, creates a **lightly obscured** area. An area of dim light is usually a boundary between a source of bright light, such as a torch, and surrounding darkness. The soft light of twilight and dawn also counts as dim light. A particularly brilliant full moon might bathe the land in dim light.

The description of [darkvision](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/adventuring#Darkvision) (PHB, p. 183-184) states:

> Many creatures in the worlds of D&D, especially those that dwell underground, have darkvision. Within a specified range, a creature with darkvision can see in darkness as if the darkness were **dim light**, so areas of darkness are only lightly obscured as far as that creature is concerned. However, the creature can’t discern color in darkness, only shades of gray.

**As a rogue with the Skulker feat (and darkvision), can I hide in the cover of darkness (with no other cover)?**

Please provide any additional RAW that would confirm or prevent this from working.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are correct. If you were in total darkness, that would be equivalent to Dim Light/Lightly Obscured to a creature with Dark Vision. However, you would still have to make a stealth check to hide, as the wording is "You can **try** to hide..." (bold added for emphasis).

Hiding (PHB p. 177)

> "When you try to hide, you make a Dexterity (Stealth) check...."

Answer (score -1):

You will have to make a stealth check, but against a perception check with disadvantage for someone without darkvision. If you add your expertise to stealth, combined with high dex, this is a sure success.

Comment: Could you add citations or an explanation of your reasoning to back up this approach?

Comment: even darkvision enabled characters would do their perception checks at a disadvantage as lightly obscured areas (like dim light) impose a disadvantage on all perception checks that rely on vision and darkness is seen as dim light (lightly obscured) by darkvision (PHB rule on vision)